# imaplib save authenticate pythone

Tags: python, email, gmail, imaplib

Sorry for my english. I use [imaplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html) for email operations. I try save authenticate, for save my password. I found method

```
IMAP4.login_cram_md5
```

but how it use?

This is my example

```
IMAP_SERVER = 'imap.gmail.com'
IMAP_PORT = '993'
IMAP_USE_SSL = True


    class MailBox(object):
        def __init__(self, user, password):
            print("MailBox __init__")
            self.user = user
            self.password = password
            if IMAP_USE_SSL:
                self.imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(IMAP_SERVER, IMAP_PORT)
            else:
                self.imap = imaplib.IMAP4(IMAP_SERVER, IMAP_PORT)

        def __enter__(self):
            print("MailBox __enter__")
            self.imap.login_cram_md5(self.user, self.password)
            return self
```

start code

```
class Main:
    main_box = MailBox('asdasd@gmail.com', 'wqeqwdsadwqeq==')
    main_box.__enter__()
```

i have error

```
imaplib.error: Unsupported AUTHENTICATE mechanism. i188mb2545835lji
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server doesn't support CRAM_MD5.

Check the CAPABILITY of a server before you try to use an extension:

```
> a CAPABILITY   
< * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH2 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN AUTH=OAUTHBEARER AUTH=XOAUTH
< a OK Thats all she wrote!
```

Gmail supports Authenticate methods XOAUTH2, PLAIN, PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN, OAUTHBEARER, and XOAUTH (plus the baseline non-authenticate LOGIN).

PLAIN is standard.  I'm not sure what PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN is.  The rest are variants of OAUTH.